If a function in a JavaScript module changes a global variable, can other functions in that module see that change?
Consider the following example
data = null

function read_data() {
    //read a file and assign data = file content
}

function print() {
    console.log(data)
}

If I call read_data and then print from another script, would it print null? Or should I call read_data every time I need to print it?

Yes since it is closed upon the data name

The code as it is won't work since assignment to an undeclared will throw on a module, but yes, global context is accessible to every module and changes to it are accessible to other modules.

"Global" is not really the best term in a module; more like, "module scoped" or "module global", because modules are firewalled from each other.

Yes if read_data changes the global variable data, then other functions in the same module can see that change. If you call read_data first and then call print, print will display the updated value of data.
